# Resources to improve my economic intuition

Tags: reference-request, self-study, soft-question

I am trying to improve my economic logic skills and ability to think about day-to-day issues in the systematic way economics and decisions science approaches scarcity or optimization.

A simple example to clarify, I know that MC=MR however the **intuition** as to why MC$<$MR is not optimal is something which educators seem to overlook to explain.

I am looking for any resources online or textbooks, workbooks, non-fiction, etc that will help me sharpen these skills.

Let me know if I can further improve my question, apologies in advance as this is my first post.

Comment: This video helps explain your example question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsxK018YXLI

Answer (score 4):

While textbooks are the best way to learn the material (MC=MR etc), here are some suggestions for improving your intuitive understanding of economics.

**Books**

[*The Undercover Economist*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345494016) by Tim Harford

[*The Armchair Economist*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451651732) by Steven E. Landesburg

**Blogs**

[*Marginal Revolution*](http://marginalrevolution.com/)

[*Noahpinion*](http://noahpinionblog.blogspot.co.uk/)

[*Conversable Economist*](http://conversableeconomist.blogspot.co.uk/)

[*The Enlightened Economist*](http://www.enlightenmenteconomics.com/blog/) (Great for book recommendations)

**Podcasts**

[*Econtalk*](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/econtalk/id135066958?mt=2) with Russ Roberts

[*FT Alphachat*](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/ft-alphachat/id448302257?mt=2)

This is just a start. Hopefully these will send you to other excellent sources.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will definitely look into these!